# Latexmk missing in TeXlive 2012

Tags: texlive, latexmk

I would like to use `latexmk` tools together with TeX Live 2012, but I could not find `latexmk`. Is it extra tools, or did TeX Live stop supporting it?

In my case, I have OS Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I have it insttalled as part of tl2012 in `$ type latexmk
latexmk is /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-cygwin/latexmk` have you run `tlmgr install latexmk`

Comment: If your TeXLive 2012 comes from ubuntu packages, run `sudo apt-get install latexmk`.

Comment: But in this way latexmk has version 4.24. Current released version is 4.35 dated 11 November 2012.

Comment: If you always want to have the latest `latexmk` version in your TeX Live, I would suppose to use the "plain TeX Live" from http://www.tug.org/texlive. Distribution's packaging is often delayed some days/weeks or even months.

Comment: If you want control of your TeX Live installation and updates to the latest packages, you'll need to do a 'vanilla' install as  explained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092. (Many of us feel this is the best approach on Linux.)

Answer (score 5):

`Latexmk` is a Perl script, and so can be installed on any system featuring a Perl set up: certainly Ubuntu has this! The [latest code](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) can be obtained from CTAN, and there are installation instructions there. Broadly, what you need to do is

1. Put the `latexmk.pl` where the 'system can find it' (`~/bin` is common for 'personal' scripts, or `/usr/local/bin` if you have root privileges and want a system-wide install).
2. Rename this file as just `latexmk`
3. Mark it as executable (`chmod 777 latexmk`)

There is a bit more detail in the docs for the script, but that should hopefully get you started.

---

Note that the 'recommended' way to have an up-to-date TeX system on Linux is to use the 'vanilla' TeX Live from TUG: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).